# How to calculate MAPE and DS in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, regression, svm

I am using fitrsvm with default, cross-validation, and KFold validations.

```
%%In sample validation.
rng default ;
mdl = fitrsvm(X,Y, 'Standardize',true);
loss =  resubLoss(mdl)
%% out of sample validation with 80% traning and 20% validation    
CVmdl = crossval(mdl,'Holdout',0.2);
CVloss = kfoldLoss(CVmdl)
%% 10Fold Cross Validation Model
KFmdl = crossval(mdl);
KFloss = kfoldLoss(KFmdl)
```

I need to calculate the MAPE and Directional Symmetry(DS) for these models. Is there any  builtin function(like loss or KfoldLoss) in Matlab? Or do I need to implement these as a functions?

Comment: Can you please tell me the reason for down so that I can avoid it future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I implemented both the Directional Symmetry(DS) and Mean Absolute Percentage Error (MAPE) as functions

```
function mape( Y, Ypredict, indxtest)
smape = 0;

    if isempty(indxtest)
        for i = 1 :length(Y)
           smape = smape + (abs((Ypredict(i) - Y(i))) / Y(i));
        end
    else
        j = find(indxtest); 
        for i = 1 :length(j)
           smape = smape + (abs((Ypredict(i) - Y(j(i)))) / Y((j(i))));
        end   
    end

mape = smape * 100/length(Y)
end
-------------------------------------------------------
function ds( Y, Ypredict, indxtest)
sds = 0;
if isempty(indxtest)
   for i = 2 :length(Y)
      if (((Y(i)-Y(i-1))*(Ypredict(i)-Ypredict(i-1))) > 0)
         sds = sds + 1;
      end
   end
else
   j = find(indxtest);   
   for i = 2 :length(j)
       if (((Y(j(i))-Y(j(i-1)))*(Ypredict((i))-Ypredict(i-1))) > 0)
           sds = sds + 1;
       end
   end
end
ds = sds * 100/length(j)
end
```

Although this works fine for me, but I will appreciate if somebody helps me to improve it either minimizing the number of lines or increasing the efficiency.